В окне приложения открывается пустой документ
В моем приложении после авторизации, пользователю в combobox видны только те документы, к которым у него есть доступ (в БД при добавлении документа и сотрудника указываю обоим уровень доступа от 1 до 4). Но при открытии выходит только пустое окно, без содержимого.
Ранее, до добавления уровней доступа, у меня правильно открывались все документы.
В БД в таблицу document в столбце name храню имя документа, а в content путь к документу, access_level - уровень доступа
в таблицу user храню логин, пароль, фио и тд и уровень доступа.
скину сюда код всех 3 форм в приложении
public partial class Avtorization : Form
{
    public static int currentUserAccessLevel;
    public Avtorization()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            String LoginUser = textBox_login.Text;
            String PassUser = textBox_password.Text;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            using (MySqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `IDUser` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP", Database.GetConnection());
                command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoginUser;
                command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PassUser;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }

            using (MySqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Access_level FROM user WHERE IDUser = @uL", connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uL", LoginUser); // Используйте LoginUser

                using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // Сохраните уровень секретности для использования в Mainform
                        Mainform.currentUserAccessLevel = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Access_level"]);

                        this.Hide();
                        Mainform mainform = new Mainform();
                        mainform.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Неверные логин или пароль. Попробуйте снова");
                        return;
                    }
                    //if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

public partial class Mainform : Form
{
    public static int currentUserAccessLevel;

    public Mainform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillComboBox();
    }

    private void FillComboBox()
    {
        // Очистка combobox
        comboBoxFiles.Items.Clear();

        // Выполнение запроса для получения имен файлов
        using (MySqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM document WHERE Access_Level <= @accessLevel", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessLevel", currentUserAccessLevel);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    comboBoxFiles.Items.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void comboBoxFiles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedFileName = comboBoxFiles.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string filePath = GetFilePath(selectedFileName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            // Создать новую форму для отображения файла
            FormFileContent formFileContent = new FormFileContent(filePath, currentUserAccessLevel);
            formFileContent.Show();
        }
    }

    private string GetFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Content FROM document WHERE Name = @fileName", connection); // Убрали проверку доступа
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);

            string filePath = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();

            return filePath;
        }
    }

    private void TextBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchText = textBoxSearch.Text.Trim();
        FillComboBox(searchText);
    }

    // Перегруженный метод для поиска файлов
    private void FillComboBox(string searchText)
    {
        // Очистка combobox
        comboBoxFiles.Items.Clear();
        using (MySqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Name, Content FROM document WHERE Name LIKE @searchText OR Content LIKE @searchText", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchText", "%" + searchText + "%");
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Формируем строку, содержащую имя и часть содержимого 
                    string itemText = $"{reader["Name"].ToString()} ({reader["Content"].ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(reader["Content"].ToString().Length, 20))})";
                    // Добавьте имя файла в combobox
                    comboBoxFiles.Items.Add(itemText);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Mainform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentUserAccessLevel = Avtorization.currentUserAccessLevel; // Доступ к статической переменной Avtorization
    }
}


public partial class FormFileContent : Form
{
    private string _filePath;
    private int _accessLevel;

    public FormFileContent(string filePath, int accessLevel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _filePath = filePath;
        _accessLevel = accessLevel;

        // Проверка доступа к файлу в FormFileContent:
        if (GetAccessLevel(_filePath) <= _accessLevel)
        {
            // Чтение и отображение файла
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_filePath).ToLower();
            try
            {
                if (extension == ".docx")
                {
                    // Чтение содержимого .docx файла
                    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_filePath, false))
                    {
                        string text = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.InnerText;
                        richTextBoxContent.Text = text;
                    }
                }
                else if (extension == ".pdf")
                {
                    // Чтение содержимого .pdf файла
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(_filePath);
                    string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1); // Читаем первую страницу
                    richTextBoxContent.Text = text;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Обработка файлов других типов (или сообщение об ошибке)
                    MessageBox.Show("Неподдерживаемый тип файла.", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Ошибка: {ex.Message}", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetAccessLevel(string filePath)
    {
        // Метод для получения уровня доступа к файлу по его пути 
        // (запрос к базе данных)
        using (MySqlConnection connection = Database.GetConnection())
        {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Access_level FROM document WHERE Content = @filePath", connection); //  Важно! Используем "Content"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filePath", filePath);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(reader["Access_level"]);
                }
            }
        }
        return -1; // Возвращаем -1, если доступ не найден
    }    
}

Пробовала запускать с точками останова,
в выводе мне писали, что пропущены символы. Думала нужно включить символы в настройках NuGet, но не смогла разобраться.
"мой проект.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: мой проект.exe). Загружено "C:путь\bin\x64\Debug\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"мой проект.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: мой проект.exe). Загружено "C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"мой проект.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: мой проект.exe). Загружено "путь\bin\x64\Debug\itextsharp.dll". Сборка модуля выполнена без символов.
Программа "[4484] мой проект.exe" завершилась с кодом 4294967295 (0xffffffff).


В button1_Click вы задаёте Mainform.currentUserAccessLevel = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Access_level"]);. После чего в Mainform_Load перезаписываете currentUserAccessLevel = Avtorization.currentUserAccessLevel;. То есть нормальное значение заменяете нулём.
